# Can't adjust height of table body for overflow scrolling

Tags: css

This might sound like a noob question but I can't for the life of me change the height of my table body.  I want it to be scroll-able using the overflow-y property but I'm unable to adjust the height of the table, even after assigning the height property to a certain value.

Here is my css for my table

```
#itemstable {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
  }

  #itemstable td {
    max-width: 115px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border: 1px solid #f7f5e6;
    padding: 8px;
  }

  #itemstable table {border: 2px solid var(--Blue)}

  #itemstable tr:nth-child(even){background-color: var(--LightBlue);}
  #itemstable tr:nth-child(odd){background-color: var(--LighterBlue);}

  #itemstable tbody tr:hover {
      background-color: var(--AccentBlue); 
      color: white;
      cursor: pointer;
    }


  #itemstable th {
    padding: 4px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: var(--Blue);
    color: white;
  }

.InvTable{
    height: 100%;
    width: 1300px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    table-layout: fixed;
}

.InvTable .TableHeaderContainer {
    border: 2px solid var(--Blue);
    background-color: var(--Blue);
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    width: 80%;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

And here is my html

```
<div>
   <div className="InvTable">
      <table id="itemstable" style={{border: '2px solid #333a56'}}>
         <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Vendor</th>
              <th>P.O #</th>
              <th>Status</th> 
             </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
             {this.RenderTableBody()}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I've tried setting the height of each one of my css variables but nothing changes, the table stays the same height.  If anyone could help me figure out why I can't change the height of my table that would be great! Thanks.

Comment: Seems like your code is only setting the `height` on the `div` containing the table, and it's setting it to `100%`. Can you please share the code that you're trying that isn't working?

Comment: @coreyward it's the css that isn't working, i tried setting the div height to any other value and it didn't change the height of the table.

Comment: Why would it? The `div.InvTable` element has the default `overflow` value of `visible`, and the `div.InvTable > table` element has not had a `height` set on it.

Comment: @coreyward I think I get what you're saying.  I need to set overflow-y to auto on ```.InvTable``` element and also set the height to something other than 100%?  Is that right or am I not understanding what you're saying?

Comment: You haven't set the height on the `table` element at all. If you want the confusingly named `div.InvTable` to scroll, then yes, give it a height that will compute (`100%` is ignored if the parent doesn't have a height, except in Webkit where it ends up similar to `100vh`) and set `overflow-y: auto` on it.

Comment: @coreyward Ok i see what you're saying sorry for the confusion.  So that makes the entire table scroll-able, but I just need the table body to scroll, instead of the whole thing.  Is that possible here?